# Restore Google VM file permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I accidentally ran "sudo make chmod -R 777 /" on my GCP, now I'm not able to access the SSH anymore (Neither by terminal or browser):

```
Permissions 0777 for '/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

How can I access my VM and restore it?

Comment: 1/2) You have a more serious problem which is that you have trashed the permissinos for the entire operating system. There are a few methods: 1) Attach the boot (root) disk to another instance and correct the file permissions. 2) Use a startup script to run commands to fix permissions. This article will show how to run startup commands: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Comment: 2/2) I recommend creating a new VM instance and attaching the old boot disk. Then copy off the files and data that you need. Then delete the old instance.

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested by *@John Hanley*, **you have (must) create a new instance to avoid serious problems in future with this broken VM**.

**To solve permissions issue** with `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` you can follow documentation [Running startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly) or/and [article suggested](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/) by *@John Hanley* to execute command `sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or follow instructions from [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b) to connect to your instance via serial console and after that run `sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to set proper permissions.

Keep in mind that restoring SSH access **WON'T SOLVE** all other possible issues with your VM related to `sudo make chmod -R 777 /`. So, you can skip it and follow instructions below:

**To move your data from broken VM to new VM** you can follow this steps:

1. create snapshot of the boot disk of broken instance

   ```
   $ gcloud compute disks snapshot BROKEN_INSTANCE_BOOT_DISK_NAME --snapshot-names=TEMPORARY_SNAPSHOT_NAME
   ```
2. create temporary disk with snapshot

   ```
   $ gcloud compute disks create TEMPORARY_DISK_NAME --source-snapshot=TEMPORARY_SNAPSHOT_NAME
   ```
3. [create new instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create)
4. attach temporary disk to new instance

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances attach-disk NEW_ISTANCE_NAME --disk=TEMPORARY_DISK_NAME
   ```
5. mount temporary disk

   ```
   $ sudo su -
   $ mkdir /mnt/TEMPORARY_DISK
   $ mount /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_TEMPORARY_DISK_NAME /mnt/TEMPORARY_DISK
   ```
6. copy data from temporary disk to new instance
7. unmount temporary disk :

   ```
   $ sudo umount /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_TEMPORARY_DISK_NAME
   ```
8. detach temporally disk

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances detach-disk NEW_ISTANCE_NAME --disk=TEMPORARY_DISK_NAME
   ```